# How can I tune the `step_impute_knn` function from the recipe package?

Tags: r, tidymodels, recipe, r-parsnip

I want to use the `step_impute_knn` function from the `recipe` package to impute missing values. This function uses the Gower distance as a distance metric, which is suitable when predictors are a mixture of categorical and continuous data. But as far as I can see, there is no way to use this function with the `tune()` parameter, since the tuning must be done on a (parsnip) model. But the only parsnip model is `nearest_neighbor` function that doesn't have Gower distance as an option.

Sample data:

```
train <- structure(list(PassengerId = c("0001_01", "0002_01", "0003_01", 
"0003_02", "0004_01", "0005_01"), HomePlanet = c("Europa", "Earth", 
"Europa", "Europa", "Earth", NA), CryoSleep = c("False", 
"False", "False", "False", "False", "False"), Cabin = c("B/0/P", 
"F/0/S", "A/0/S", "A/0/S", "F/1/S", "F/0/P"), Destination = c("TRAPPIST-1e", 
"TRAPPIST-1e", "TRAPPIST-1e", "TRAPPIST-1e", "TRAPPIST-1e", "PSO J318.5-22"
), Age = c(39, 24, 58, 33, 16, 44), VIP = c("False", "False", 
"True", "False", "False", "False"), RoomService = c(0, 109, 43, 
0, 303, 0), FoodCourt = c(0, 9, 3576, 1283, 70, 483), ShoppingMall = c(0, 
25, 0, 371, 151, 0), Spa = c(0, 549, 6715, 3329, 565, 291), VRDeck = c(0, 
44, 49, 193, 2, 0), Name = c("Maham Ofracculy", "Juanna Vines", 
"Altark Susent", "Solam Susent", "Willy Santantines", "Sandie Hinetthews"
), Transported = c("False", "True", "False", "False", "True", 
"True")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I have so far:

```
train_no_na <- train %>%
na.omit()

imp_knn_blueprint <- recipe(Transported ~ ., data = train_no_na) %>%
     step_impute_knn(recipe = ., HomePlanet, 
              impute_with = imp_vars(.), neighbors = 5, 
              options = list(nthread = 1, eps = 1e-08))

imp_knn_prep <- prep(imp_knn_blueprint, training = train_no_na)
imp_knn_5 <- bake(imp_knn_prep, new_data = train)
```

Is there some way to use the `tidymodels` and `parsnip` workflows to tune the knn-function that is used inside the `step_impute_knn`? I've tried reading the code for the function but don't see which engine they use.

EDIT: To be clear, I'd like to tune the `neighbours` parameter inside `step_impute_knn` via some grid search, rather than having to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `tune()` neighbors in `step_impute_knn` similarly to other hyperparameters in recipe steps.

```
library(tidymodels)


train_folds <- vfold_cv(train_no_na, v = 3)

imp_knn_blueprint <- recipe(Transported ~ ., data = train_no_na) %>%
  step_impute_knn(HomePlanet, 
                  impute_with = imp_vars(all_predictors()), neighbors = tune::tune(), 
                  options = list(nthread = 1, eps = 1e-08))

log_spec <- logistic_reg()

# Update range as appropriate
knn_params <- extract_parameter_set_dials(imp_knn_blueprint) %>%
  update(neighbors = neighbors(c(1L, 10L)))

knn_grid <- grid_regular(knn_params,
                         levels = c(
                          neighbors = 10
                         ))

knn_wf <- 
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(log_spec) %>%
  add_recipe(imp_knn_blueprint)

impute_knn_tune <-
  knn_wf %>%
  tune_grid(
    train_folds,
    grid = knn_grid,
    metrics = metric_set(roc_auc, accuracy)
  )
```

Comment: This seems to do something, however, I'm now not sure what.
- What does the `log_spec` model do in this case? 
- Also, the way I set up the recipe is to train on data without NA and then bake it on data with NA. Perhaps I need to tune it on data with NAs for the evaluation to make sense? Or how is it calculating the ROC and accuracy of the imputation without any NAs?

Comment: To tune the `neighbors` parameter you need something to assess. I didn't know what sort of model this was ultimately being plugged into and just chose a logistic regression specification, which is were that `log_spec` object comes from. The code I shared won't actually return any classification from the provided sample data, I just wanted to show an example of the full workflow. Rather than splitting your data into w/ NA and w/o, split it into training and testing. Make CV folds from the training data, and do this grid tuning on that set, evaluating with the reserved test data.

Comment: Aha, I think I get it now. There is no way to tune just the actual imputation but rather, the tuning has to be done together with the final model that I'll use to predict the outcome?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use the same model you plan to use in making predictions, but you do need some way to compare different numbers of `neighbors`. I'd choose a model specification and target metric that makes the most sense for your classification problem. Once you identify the # of neighbors that you like, you could always fix that parameter and use the recipe with a different model. In `tidymodels` you can build a `workflowset` which is a convenient way to run multiple model specs for direct comparison.